Github actions - Is it possible to pull a Linux based image using Linux containers in Docker on a Windows runner?
Is there a way to switch to Linux containers in Docker on a Windows runner in GitHub Actions? I need to pull a Linux-based image, and my tests require a Windows machine to build and run.
The only way I can get around that is to host my own Windows agent runner with HyperV enabled but this looks like too much work.
There seems to be a closed issue about that on GitHub https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/904
Do you guys know any workaround?

In order to run containers on windows, you need to install wsl (windows subsystem for linux), check out this action

It doesn't support WSLv2 with HyperV which is required to pull a linux based image.
